# Calling different commands in Dockerfiles depending on environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

What is the best way to call different `npm` scripts from a `Dockerfile` depending on type of environment (i.e. development or production)?

My current `Dockerfile` is below:

```
FROM node:12.15.0-alpine

ARG env

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./ /usr/app

CMD npm run start

EXPOSE 5000
```

Ideally I would either like to be able to run a npm run start:development script, or start:production script.

I have tried a mix of ARG and ENV variables to get the desired effect. However judging from the below closed GitHub issue, they are not available in the correct part of the cycle that I would require.

i.e.

```
CMD npm run start:${env}
```

Primarily I am wondering if there is a preferred methodology that is used to keep everything in one `Dockerfile`.

Edit:

I have had some sort of success with the below code, but sometimes it causes my terminal to become unresponsive.

```
RUN if [ "$env" = "production" ]; then \
    npm run start:prod; \
  else \
    npm run start:dev; \
  fi
```

Comment: Why do you want to run different scripts per environment? That seems to defeat the purpose somewhat.

Comment: Primarily as I need to run nodemon on my development environment to restart the Node.js application automatically with code changes, but I want to use traditional node in production.

Comment: I'd suggest having different containers for the two purposes, then. For one thing, you'll want to have the development dependencies and a mounted volume in dev, vs production only dependencies and no volume in prod. If you try and have a single container, you'll likely end up with a bunch of stuff in your production images that has no business being there.

Comment: So essentially you could suggest two different docker-compose files calling different Dockerfiles for each purpose?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing in the compose file, you haven't shown that so I don't know. But I'd certainly recommend different Dockerfiles for a development environment vs deployment.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Surely though I would need separate docker-compose files to call the different Dockerfiles depending on environment type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dockerfile is running in a 'build' context, so any variables available are related to the build environment (when you run `docker build`), not the execution environment. The build process is running only the first time when you build the image.

If you want to use environment variables defined at execution time, you could use a `CMD` pointing to a container script. Inside this script, all environment variables are available from the initial execution (container start).

Dockerfile

```
...
COPY ./scripts /script/path
CMD /script/path/test.sh
```

./scripts/test.sh

```
cd /your/app/path
echo ENV = $ENV
npm run start:$ENV
```

Also you could review the best practices for Dockerfiles with good examples and use cases

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: Perfect that was just what I was looking for. Thank you for the additional reading as well.